# hPlot (rCharts) pie chart - slices order in shiny

Tags: r, pie-chart, rcharts, shiny

I'm using `hPlot` (`rCharts`) in shiny app for pie chart type. I have an ordered data frame (by slice size). However, it seems like it doesn't take into account the data frame order and keep showing the pie chart slices in alphabetic order of x (labels). Any idea how can I force hPlot to order the slices by slice size?

```
dfx <- data.frame(key = c("b","g","a", "c"), value = c(1, 2, 3,4))

hPlot(x = "key", y = "value", data = df, type = "pie")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide what you've got so far

Comment: @PorkChop any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hPlot` is actually a function from `rCharts`.

But to your question, you have to reorder the factors, as R orders them alphabetically by default. And a character vector is converted by default to a factor vector unless you change some global settings (it is not advised to do that).

So this gives you what you want for example:

```
# To install rCharts
#
# library(devtools)
# install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')
#
library(rCharts)


cvek <- c("b","g","a", "c")
df <- data.frame(ckey = cvek, value = c(1, 2, 3,4),stringsAsFactors=F)

df$fkey <- factor(df$ckey,levels=cvek)

hPlot(x = "fkey", y = "value", data = df, type = "pie",title="By Order (fkey)")
```

yielding this:

[image]